Multitexture with one object/one material
I have 3 books and I want one book to be red, one green, one blue. However all 3 books should be one object. I do not want to separate them. How can I assign all three colors without using material slots and by using only one material output? In Corona this is can be achieved with a multitexture map. I managed to assign red and green by using a mix color node with a geometry/random per island plugged into factor. However I do not know how to do it for more than 2 colors.


You can group all the shader nodes besides the color input, and use this group in 3 materials. Everything inside the group will be linked between copies of the group. Does it answer your question ? Basically 3 shaders with the structure Color > YourGroup > Output

Can you please show me a picture of the material setup, I'm very new to blender.

Select all nodes besides RGB and Output, Ctrl+G (group), Tab (exit group), then create 2 other materials with only another RGB value. You can either duplicate the material or copy-paste the nodes in a new material.

Is it correct to assume that each book is a single mesh island ?

All three books are merged into one object. I actually need a solution for something else but I used books as an example.

Thats the thing I want only one material.

You could use a Texture Coordinate (Generated output) Gradient Texture > ColorRamp (Constant mode) with your 2 colors:

If you need to put different image textures onto your object, combine your different images into one, unwrap your meshes and move the UV islands over the image until you're good:


I used colors in my example but I actually need to plug different textures.

In that case use a multitexture map in blender as well?

How? Where is it?

create a map with your images, unwrap your objects and put each UV island over the part of the image that they are supposed to display?

I've edited my answer but I'm still not sure it answers

Yes this is possible, but the problem is when you have 10 wood planks with 10 rough, 10 bump and 10 refl maps.

Shoot, you didn't want a multi-material solution ... My bad, look at moonboots solution.

Nodes inside a group will all be the same between copies of the group. Basically any copy of, say, YourGroup will be linked between them.
Step 1
Starting with your shader :

Step 2
Group the nodes (including RGB just to simplify the process) with Ctrl+G

Step 3
Delete the RGB node and plug the color as input of your group

Step 4
Exit group with Tab, and add a RGB node

Step 5
Duplicate the material into a new one. There will be no link to the original material besides the group we created

Creates a new slot (hey Blender, I'll need another material on this object)
Select your red shader (hey Blender, I want this slot to use the red shader)
Make a single-copy of the red shader (hey Blender, make me a copy of the shader not linked to the original)


Step 6
Repeat for the third material.
Step 7
Go to Edit Mode, select one book, select the correct material, click Assign
And you're flying.

Anything inside the group will be the same between materials. Only difference will be the color you plugged as an input.
So all changes inside one copy of the group will also change the other copies :


Thank you, this was helpful.

(Using Blender 4.2.3)

GeometryNodes modifier: It is attached to the object made of parts. The Island Index of each part is cached using a Store Named Attribute node.
Shader: The Island Index is recovered using an Attribute node. Its value is Compared to successive integers to implement a Switch-Case operator.
(Blender 4.2.3+)

Thank you. I will try it.
